# PHP post syntax variables

Tags: php

I m learning PHP , and I m posting variable from a HTML form

Below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to PHP Products</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$txt1=$_POST["product_form_no"];
$txt2=$_POST["product_form_name"];
$txt3=$_POST["product_form_desc"];

<h1>The Entered Product</h1>

<p>Product No</p>echo $txt1;
<p>Product Name</p>echo $txt2;
<p>Product Desc</p>echo $txt3;

 ?> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

I m getting the below error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in C:\wamp\www\product_entered_list.php on line 12

Any help would be helpful !!!

Comment: You want the ?> before <h1> to drop back to HTML there, not before </body>

Comment: Army of personal lint-checkers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$txt1=$_POST["product_form_no"];
$txt2=$_POST["product_form_name"];
$txt3=$_POST["product_form_desc"];

?>   <---missing
```

Without that closing `?>`, you're still in "PHP mode" when the `<h1`> is reached, and PHP tries to interpret that as PHP code, not HTML.

This means you'll also have to modify your echo lines:

```
<p>Product No</p><?php echo $txt1; ?>
                 ^^^^^^           ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try closing php tag before "The Entered Product", after that, open php tags for each echo and close them. Code will be like the following:

```
<?php
$txt1=$_POST["product_form_no"];
$txt2=$_POST["product_form_name"];
$txt3=$_POST["product_form_desc"];
?>
<h1>The Entered Product</h1>

<p>Product No</p><?php echo $txt1; ?>
<p>Product Name</p><?php echo $txt2; ?>
<p>Product Desc</p><?php echo $txt3; ?>
```

Tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this... you need to use the closing php tag before writing the HTML.

This is true for both your POST variable section as well as where you echo the 3 variable values

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>Welcome to PHP Products</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
    $txt1=$_POST["product_form_no"];
    $txt2=$_POST["product_form_name"];
    $txt3=$_POST["product_form_desc"];
 ?>
 <h1>The Entered Product</h1>

 <p>Product No</p> <?php echo $txt1; ?>
 <p>Product Name</p><?php echo $txt2; ?>
 <p>Product Desc</p><?php echo $txt3; ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
$txt3=$_POST["product_form_desc"];

<h1>The Entered Product</h1>

<p>Product No</p>echo $txt1;
```

Right in the middle of the PHP you start using HTML. You must first close the PHP tags, or use echo to print out the HTML.

Do either this:

```
$txt3=$_POST["product_form_desc"];

?>

<h1>The Entered Product</h1>

<p>Product No</p><?= $txt1 ?>
```

Or this:

```
$txt3=$_POST["product_form_desc"];

echo"<h1>The Entered Product</h1>";

echo "<p>Product No</p>" . $txt1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tags missing. Closing one after variable assignment, closing & opening around the echos. I'd suggest going back one step and start with PHP basics.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you've typed HTML inbetween the `<?php ?`> tags, also known as a syntax error :))

In future make sure to use PHP's [echo](http://php.net/echo) function to correctly display output.

```
echo "<h1>The Entered Product</h1>";

echo "<p>Product No " . $txt1 . "</p>";
echo "<p>Product Name</p>" . $txt2;
echo "<p>Product Desc</p>" . $txt3;
```

On a side note, displaying data on a page, directly from the form is fine if you're learning and the script is not going to be public. However, if you intend to do any serious coding (i.e. the public will use the script) you may want to read up a-bit on [form security](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/2.html).

Answer (score 0):

In your code at line number 6  PHP code begins and at line number 11 HTML code begins, php tags were not closed so that code as well gets interpreted. So "<" at beginning of line number 11 causes FATAL error as it is not recognized PHP code.

To incorporate HTML code in PHP you can either use PHP opening and closing tags  to merge HTML and PHP code in one file. OR you can use quotes "" to make html code as string to PHP and echo that.

Below is method 1:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to PHP Products</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
   $txt1=$_POST["product_form_no"];
   $txt2=$_POST["product_form_name"];
   $txt3=$_POST["product_form_desc"];

   echo "
    <h1>The Entered Product</h1>
    <p>Product No</p>$txt1
    <p>Product Name</p>$txt2
    <p>Product Desc</p>$txt3";
?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Method 2:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to PHP Products</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
   $txt1=$_POST["product_form_no"];
   $txt2=$_POST["product_form_name"];
   $txt3=$_POST["product_form_desc"];
?>  
<h1>The Entered Product</h1>
<p>Product No</p><?php echo $txt1;?>
    <p>Product Name</p><?php echo$txt2;?>
    <p>Product Desc</p><?php echo $txt3;?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please don't recommend that anyone uses w3schools; it has been widely discredited: http://w3fools.com/